# Hitting done on keyboard clears the text in flutter

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

I have a `TextField()` and, a controller, which I'm passing it to the `TextField` controller. My problem is that every time I hit done in my keyboard it clears my text.

I have followed this question: [Flutter keyboard done button causes textfield content to vanish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946081/flutter-keyboard-done-button-causes-textfield-content-to-vanish)
 question to solve my problem but nothing is working out for me. I'm clueless hence putting this question again on the StackOverflow.

**MY CODE:**

```
class ReferralPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
         child: Card(
           color: Colors.white,
           child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: TextField(
                 controller: controller,
                 cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Referral Code'),
              )
           )
         ),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
          new BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(173, 179, 191, 0.3), blurRadius: 20.0, offset: new Offset(0, 12))
         ])
     )
   );
 }
}
```

As you can see my `TextEditingController()` is not inside the `Widget build` so there is no sense of happening that.

> The only solution I found to this problem was to remove the controller but I don't want to do this, I want to use my controller for other purposes. I don't know why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a short suggestion, whenever you create a ```screen``` don't use ```StatelessWidget```, normally a screen will have a lot of changes and logic which suggest that it should be a ```StatefullWidget```. Also the widget is rebuild every time due to the keyboard animation, a ```StatefulWidget``` is your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this issue because you are making use of a stateless widget. Change your stateless widget to a stateful widget so that your controller won't get rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you **nonbrighto**, it helped. But I really think why the `StatelessWidget` rebuilds it every time.

Comment: You are welcome! That is the default behavior of stateless widget. It doesn't maintain state.